# Command to clone a table (structure/data) in T-SQL

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, clone

I need to create a "copy" of all my tables, structure and data.

Is there any way to do it via T-SQL? I'm aware of the "Script As -> Create" option, but I'd like to have something completely "not binded" to the query itself.

Is there something like:

```
CLONE TABLE A FROM B
```

or

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE dbo.spCloneTable(B, A)?
```

Otherwise (I have an application that access the DB via Entity Framework) is there any command like to do that? I'd expect something like this.

```
var B = MyDBInstance.TableB.Find(ID);
var A = B.Clone();
MyDBInstance.Add(A);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just copy the schema try this code:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO B FROM A
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something like this?

```
    CREATE TABLE B SELECT * FROM A LIMIT 0;
```

OR

```
    SELECT * INTO B FROM A WHERE 1=0;
```